How to pass a function with multiple arguments as a callback/function pointer?
I've been trying to refactor some code and eventually stumbled upon a problem when calling a Thread.onRun( (*callback) () ) function now with a function with arguments foo(unsigned long, int, int[])
I've tried using function pointers as a couple of questions/tutorials indicated but all of them result in the error

'cannot initialize a parameter of type void(*)() with an rvalue of type void':

 void (*fooPointer)(unsigned long, int, int[]) = foo;
 thread.onRun( fooPointer(longVar, intVar, intListVar));


Note that this works fine in functions with no arguments:
 thread.onRun(func);

Edit: I've implemented the solution proposed by @Delta_G to create a runner() function that only runs the function with arguments
void foo(int a, int b, int c){return a + b + c;}
void runner(){
 foo(x, y, z);
}

Note: the solution here is specifically for arduino environments, which behave differently to normal c++ and thus std::thread was not used


what is thread ?

fooPointer(longVar, intVar, intListVar) calls the function which returns void. On the other hand func is a function pointer

Check this

Do you use std::thread? If so have you ever looked at lambda expressions and/or std;:function ?

::std::function, ::std::forward and ::std::invoke are your friends if you want to refactor on modern C++.

The type for the callback function is expected to be a function that takes no arguments.  This means that there's no way to pass arguments to it.
Your only option is change the function to take no arguments and place what would be the arguments into global variables that the function will read.

btw in general the required arguments (or no arguments) of a callback function would be determined by the used context, kinda just a generic placeholder with casting to pointer. For example GLIB's GCallback for GSignal API.

The onRun function takes as an argument a function that returns void and takes no arguments.  You want to pass in a function that takes arguments.  When onRun calls this function, how would it know what arguments to pass in?  It expects to be calling a function with no arguments.
The only solution for you is to create a function that takes no arguments and calls the function with arguments that you want to call.  Then you can attach that no-argument function as your callback.
void callBack() {
   someFunctionWithArguments(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

thread.onRun(callBack);


we don't know what onRun accepts as parameters. Its not necessarily only functions

@463035858_is_not_an_ai We do know the parameter for onRun from the posted error message.
